# double clicking on file is not able to locate path

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, app-config

I have an app.config file where in I have a section for specifying the path of file to load it using reflection. Luckily assembly to be loaded and application .exe both are at same place. therefore, I have added following section in app.config

```
<pluing name = "xyz" path = "1P.SlotAssignment">
```

// path is simply name of assembly as it is located in the same folder where .exe is.

It seems to work fine when I open .exe from shortcut. But if I double click a file(file which is created and saved at different location via my .exe) to open in my application, then it crashes.
 Because in this case,  the path it looks is where file is located. It is not searching where .exe of application is located(~programfiles).

So, How to configure the path in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple solution generate your assembly dynamically path by concating

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```

and path from:

If you share your assembly load code i can help with that

Comment: I am aware of that solution but that would required code changes. I want to do something with config file